# Using a specific field of the Model Class to fill a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, model

I have a utility that loads excel files and fills up the Model with instances that have three fields:
cellValue (content of the excel cell),
column (column of the excel cell),
row (row of the excel cell).
I have several instances of the Model class in an observable collection in the ViewModel, and that observable collection is binded to the Data Grid. When I run the program, the Data Grid shows all three fields, but I only want the cell value to be shown. Is there a way to specify which field will be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off [`AutoGenerateColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `DataGrid`, then specify column you want to display explicitly:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CellValue" Binding="{Binding YourCellValueProperty}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This snippet assumes, that cell values are of simple types (text, numbers, etc). If you want more complex view for the cell value, then [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a way to go.